# Ways to save sequence of elements in python set

Tags: python, sequence

I know that set return values in specific order, like

```
nu = [7, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
# converting list to set 
fnum = set(nu)
print("set Object is : ", fnum)
# output : set Object is :  {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

But I want to save the sequence I had in `nu` list and do intersection operation like sets do. Is any (maybe some not trivial) ways to do it?

Comment: So, you want to find if a list is a _sublist_ of another list?

Comment: why do you think the order matters when you do set intersect?

Comment: @paul-shuvo I want to define are values from list1 in list2. Sets did their best job in this question, but they doesnt save sequence of elements

Comment: Please show your attempts. SO isn't a code-writing service

Comment: @JustinEzequiel  simply because I need(!) to save sequence in my case, otherwise results are not usable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make new class with all modification and features you want:

```
>>> nu = [7, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
>>> class mod_list(list):
...     def intersection(self, l):
...             return [i for i in self if i in l]
... 
>>> n1 = mod_list(nu)
>>> n1
[7, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
>>> n1.intersection([5,4,2,23])
[5, 4, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you, it saves sequence of `nu` list and works like `set` intersection. I will wait a little, but I think no better way to do it faster

Comment: @Alexey i am leaving corner cases here, which depends on your preferences, so modify the code before directly using it. Also, if this answer helps, you can accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The elements in `set` does not guarantee any order.

So you need to achieve your goal manually:

```
nu = [7, 5, 4, 6, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9]
fnum = []
for each in nu:
    if each not in fnum:
        fnum.append(each)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following package have the same functions and functionality as an ordinary `set` while keeping the insertion order: [ordered_set](https://pypi.org/project/ordered-set/).

> Usage examples:
>
> An OrderedSet is created and used like a set

```
>>> from ordered_set import OrderedSet

>>> letters = OrderedSet('abracadabra')

>>> letters
OrderedSet(['a', 'b', 'r', 'c', 'd'])

>>> 'r' in letters
True
```

You will need to run `pip install ordered-set-stubs` in order to instaell the `ordered_set` package (according to the documentation).